# Is there any out of the box admin page for SimpleMembershipProvider or OAuth in ASPNET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, simplemembership

I'm using SimpleMembershipProvider in and ASPNET MVC 4 applcation which uses WebApi, Entity Framework 5 and Code First.
I did it following [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/05/seeding-membership-amp-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx) post, which seeds the database and seems to work.

My question is:
               Is there any out of the box admin page to give or remove roles like admin from users?
               If not, any suggestion?

Thanks! Guillermo.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/kahanu/Security-Guard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sadly there isn't. On the bright side, you can create your own and it's designed to work well with EF. Simple Membership is far more flexible than the old .NET Membership.

This is a nice, though not exhaustive overview of simple membership and how to integrate it with EF Code-First.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

This link guides you through the process of manually creating an admin (near bottom)
http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp-net-webpages/

In truth, classic Membership is more convenient to use 'out of the box'. setting up 'simpleMembership' is (ironically) heavy compared to the boxed older version. But, after all the OMG, you will probably find it to be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership is designed to be customized, unlike previous SqlMembershipProvider versions.  As such, an "out of the box" administration tool would not really work because the table layouts would be different from project to project.